# VMware Workstation 9 does not work in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: vmware-workstation

I get the error reported by those that install Workstation 10, but their fix of updating the filter.c does not work. The error occurs after installing. It has to compile modules the first time it is run.

```
Failed to build vmci.  Failed to execute the build command.
Starting VMware services:
Virtual machine monitor                                             done
Virtual machine communication interface                             failed
VM communication interface socket family                            done
Blocking file system                                                done
Virtual ethernet                                                    failed
VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
```

I will uninstall and run again to get a better log, because I did apply that patch which doesn't work for Workstation 9.

Has anyone got it to work yet? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working. I had similar errors as you using Workstation 9.0.2. I then installed 9.0.3, and the only module that failed to build was Virtual ethernet. I then used the patch for the vmnet module found here: [VMware modules & kernel 3.13](http://ping8888.com/2013/12/13/vmware-modules-kernel-3-13/)

It is intended for Workstation 10, but it also worked for me using 9.0.3. I actually used the patch linked near the bottom of the page: [vmware 3.13](http://pastebin.com/p3bkbAMu). The patching actually failed (I'm not sure why, I didn't dig into it) but I was able to manually make the changes from the patch and that worked fine.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  I had been looking for a fix for this for a month!  It worked great.  I appreciate you taking the time to let us know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this patch though it refers to VMWare Player, worked for me with VMWare Workstation 9.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.  Follow the commands exactly.

http://dandar3.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/vmware-player-601-on-ubuntu-1404-alpha.html

Comment: Worked exactly as described for Workstation 9.0.4 as well.